# prove that function f() is continous when $ |(f(x)-f(y))|\leq 15|x-y|$

Tags: limits, continuity

Let f be a function from real numbers to real numbers. The following holds for the function:

$ |(f(x)-f(y))|\leq 15|x-y|$

How do I prove that the function is continuous?

(Utilizing the limit concept of continuity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is continuous in $x_0$ if
$$\forall \varepsilon>0 \ \exists \delta : |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq \varepsilon$$

So, fix $\varepsilon>0$. We have $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq15|x-x_0|$, so it's enough to pick $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{15}$:

$$|x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq15|x-x_0|\leq 15 \delta=15\frac{\varepsilon}{15}=\varepsilon$$

For some intuition, fix a point $f(x_0)$. This condition says that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq15|x-x_0|$. Eliminating absolute values, we get
$$f(x_0)-15|x-x_0|<f(x)<f(x_0)+15|x-x_0|$$
so that means $f(x)$ should be between the cone formed by the lines $f(x_0)+15(x-x_0)$ and $f(x_0)-15(x-x_0)$, as can be seen in the image (for $x_0=0$):

[image]

Comment: Could you give some intutition on how this condition implies continuity? (On a graph, perhaps)

Comment: @flytothesurface Thank you. Should there not be a "for all of x" quantifier in the definition of continuous?

Comment: @Dole you mean in like 
$$\forall \varepsilon >0 \ \exists \delta>0: \forall x: |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$$

If it's yes, it's implied in the "$\Rightarrow$", it says that "whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$, then... But I'm aware some authors write it.

Comment: @TheCrypticCat I edited my answer according to your comment.

Comment: @flytothesurface Thanks!